# Ionic 2 will not let me loop over an object of objects using *ngFor

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am developing an app where users can search for classified ads.

However, I am unable to display the search results.

Here is my search_results.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'; 
import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular'; 
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
     selector: 'page-page1',
     templateUrl: 'search_results.html' })

 export class SearchResults {
     public term: any;
     public ads: any;
     public tmp: any;

     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public params: NavParams, public http: Http) {
         this.term = this.params.get('term');
         this.ads = [];
         this.tmp = [];

         console.log("this.term", this.term);

         this.http.get('http://www.truckers.host/app/search-ads.php')
          .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data =&gt; {
            console.log("this is returned from http.get", data);
        });
     }

     ngOnInit() {
         // Let's navigate from TabsPage to Page1
         console.log(this.params);
     } }
```

Now, in my search_results.html to display the search results, I am not getting anything to print.

Here is that code:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>
            <img src="assets/images/trucker-to-trucker-logo.png" />
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="card-background-page">
    <ion-card>

        <ion-card-header>
            Search Results
        </ion-card-header>

        <ion-card-content>
            Searching for: <b>{{ term }}</b>
        </ion-card-content>

    </ion-card>

    <ion-card>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let ad of ads">
                {{ ad.ad_id }}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Nothing is returned, or iterated over.

When I console.log(data), I get an Object of Objects, and Ionic does not want to loop them.

Please let me know what other information I should include to help.

Comment: You never put the data in this.ads?

Comment: @Sandrooco here is the format of the data being returned by the http.get: http://imgur.com/UYd8dOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*ngFor` only supports for `Array` and not `Json Object`.
You should consider using a custom `Pipe` to convert Object to Array.

Documentation about [Pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html).

```
@Pipe({name: 'toArray'})
export class ToArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(inputObj: any, arg: any) {
    if (!inputObj) { return [] }

    let arr = []; 
    for(let key in inputObj) {
      // Option1 (only value without the json object's key)
      // this way will lose the key of Json Object
      //arr.push(inputObj[key]);

      // OPtion2 (both the key and value)
      let obj = {};
      obj[key] = inputObj[key];
      arr.push(obj);
    }
    return arr;
  }  
}
```

Then add it to declarations of `NgModule`, and use it in your temple this way:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let ad of ads | ToArray">
  ...
</ion-item>
```

Comment: I've read that before, but I'm totally new at ionic, and semi new at angular, so I've never used pipes. Can you link me to a decent intro to them so I understand what's going on?

Comment: @JayDoughty OK, I have add a documentation link to Angular's Pipe.

Comment: Also, where would I place that? outside of my other export class?

Comment: @JayDoughty you should place it in your app folder, same level to service.

Comment: Alright, then I have some reading to do! Thanks. I'll accept as soon as I read and comprehend <3

Comment: So the pipe is supposed to go into its own file? Do I need to call it anywhere?

Comment: @JayDoughty as I answered, you should import it in your `RootModule` which is anotated by `NgModule`.

Comment: Very new to this, so sorry. I'll try to figure it out from here.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work if I assign this.ads = data[1]; And then run the Pipe, but the data I am working with is an object of objects that looks like this: http://imgur.com/UYd8dOM -- I got the code you gave me to work only if I assign ads to data[1]. If I just assign it to data, I get nothing outputting.

Comment: I ended up doing it another way, but I believe your way did work for a non-nested object.